# What cause "Slow Frame" even though the activity doesn't do any heavy computation?

Tags: android

Here's the logic of my simple app:

1. First check if user is logged or or not.
2. If not then go to 4 . Otherwise, check if it's the 1st time of running the app or not.
3. If this is 1st time, display WizardActivity. Otherwise, display LoginActivity
4. Display MainActivity.

Here's the code of the WizardActivity, which I set as launcher on AndroidManifest.xml

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WizardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnDone;
    PrefStartUp pref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wizard);

        pref = new PrefStartUp(getApplicationContext());
        pref.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);

        btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
        btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent iii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(iii);
                finish();
            }
        });

        if (!pref.isLoggedIn()){

            if (pref.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
                Intent iii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WizardActivity.class);
                startActivity(iii);
                finish();
            }
            else {
                Intent iii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(iii);
                finish();
            }
        }
        else {
            Intent iii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(iii);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

This activity doesn't do anything. Only contains a TextView and a Button, which will call LoginActivity if is clicked. Yet when I run the app for 1st time, WizardActivity doesn't show anything. Only blank screen.

logcat showed this:

> 2019-09-14 23:07:54.447 15461-15461/com.anta40.app.logindemo
>   I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:47372820
>   intent:Intent { cmp=com.anta40.app.logindemo/.WizardActivity }
>   2019-09-14 23:07:54.645 15461-15461/com.anta40.app.logindemo W/Looper:
>   Slow Frame: doFrame is 427ms late 2019-09-14 23:07:54.883
>   15461-15461/com.anta40.app.logindemo I/Timeline: Timeline:
>   Activity_launch_request time:47373255 intent:Intent {
>   cmp=com.anta40.app.logindemo/.WizardActivity } 2019-09-14 23:07:55.079
>   15461-15461/com.anta40.app.logindemo W/Looper: Slow Frame: doFrame is
>   416ms late 2019-09-14 23:07:55.292
>   15461-15461/com.anta40.app.logindemo I/Timeline: Timeline:
>   Activity_launch_request time:47373665 intent:Intent {
>   cmp=com.anta40.app.logindemo/.WizardActivity } 2019-09-14 23:07:55.484
>   15461-15461/com.anta40.app.logindemo W/Looper: Slow Frame: doFrame is
>   387ms late 2019-09-14 23:07:55.730
>   15461-15461/com.anta40.app.logindemo I/Timeline: Timeline:
>   Activity_launch_request time:47374103 intent:Intent {
>   cmp=com.anta40.app.logindemo/.WizardActivity

This is the full code: https://github.com/anta40/LoginDemo

What's wrong here?

Comment: A guess `WizardActivity.class` is starting over and over .. some logic is not setting the correct `boolean` values correctly making it finish and start in a cycle.  Also it doesn't seem logical that this activity would send an `Intent` to launch itself anyway.

Comment: @MarkKeen Yeah I just noticed a very wrong logic: the Login and Wizard activities "call" each other. My solution is adding a Splash activity, set this as launcher, and move all the nessary SharedPreferences-related logic on it. Now my app works fine.